# IronPython exception jumps to last line

Tags: debugging, exception, ironpython, ptvs

Given a very simple example:

```
print('Hello world')
raise Exception()
print('Hello world 2')
```

When the exception is raised while debugging in VS12 with PTVS installed it breaks on the last line of code in that file (3). I would expect it to stop at line 2. I tried out different command line parameters like `-X:Tracing` or `-X:Frames` but I couldn't get the application to break where the exception actually happens. It seems like there is no line information but when I look at the details of the exception I can get this through the stack trace.

Comment: Are you debugging in managed mode, or in pure Python mode? (managed is when you see mangled function names in the call stack)

Comment: @PavelMinaev I have set Launch mode to IronPython (.NET) launcher and Interpreter to IronPython 64-bit 2.7. I can also debug C# code when doing this.

Comment: In this case you're not actually utilizing PTVS debugging at all - it just provides the editing experience, but the debugger is the core VS language-agnostic managed debugger, which uses source information that is provided by IronPython. So this is really a bug on IronPython side of things, in that it didn't report proper line number for a managed exception that it raised.

Comment: How would I actually use PTVS debugging then?

Comment: That's what gets used if you switch Launcher to Standard. It's generally much more Python aware, and will give uniformly better results on Python code - not just with exceptions, but also with variables etc. But then you will lose the ability to debug C# code.

Comment: I don't need to debug C# code, but it's necessary to debug .NET objects in the IronPython environment. I will try out that mode!